# MVC EditorForModel Freeman

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, editorformodel

I'm reading a book *Pro ASP.NET MVC3 Framework - Freeman Sandersan* where it's shown how to make simple administration im web shop.
The problem is when I try to save changes of one product it does not save.

Edit view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.EditorForModel()
<input type="submit" value="Save" />}
```

Edit method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Product product)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        repository.SaveProduct(product);
        TempData["message"] = string.Format("{0} has been saved", product.Name);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    // there is something wrong with the data values
    return View(product);
}
```

Save product method:

```
private EFDbContext context=new EFDbContext();
public void SaveProduct(Product product)
{
    if (product.ProductID == 0)
    {
        context.Products.Add(product);
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Results of editing: I change the name of the product to "Kayakkkkkkkkkk". Temp message says that saving completed but the name of product is still "Kayak".
[image: Results of editing]

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

```
public void SaveProduct(Product product)
{
    if (product.ProductID == 0)
    {
        context.Products.Add(product);
    }
    else
    {
        context.Products.Attach(product);
        context.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```